# 4-month old dislikes when diaper is strapped on - sign of a problem?

Tags: infant, diaper

Recently, my 4-month old has developed a distaste for strapping in on a diaper - he's perfectly fine when one is being taken off, and during the entire process of cleaning and preparing him, but gets exceptionally fussy when it's time to attach the velcro straps to the diaper.

Is there anything specific that might cause discomfort during the strapping-on part of diaper changing?

Comment: I hate to ask this, but is he circumcised? If so, he might be suffering physical pain from the diaper.

Comment: You're talking about the velcro straps of a disposable diaper?  Have you experimented with cotton and safety pins, just to compare?

Comment: nick012000 - Yes but he's healed fully from that. 
aparente001 - Yes, but we aren't really prepared to try cotton and safety pins.

Comment: If you don't see redness or a rash of some kind, and he settles once you've finished, it's certainly not because he's circumcised. It might be that he simply enjoys being free/naked. Does he settle once you're done? What, exactly, are you worried about? (We can't address medical concerns.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse He does settle down once the diaper is actually on - I'm just worried that/if I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Zibbobz - :)  No, you're not doing anything wrong. You can try fastening it a bit more loosely (if he's not walking/cruising, it won't fall off), but it's probably that he just likes being naked (a lot of babies do, when it's not cold.) Being a first-time parent is nerve-wracking, isn't it? It was for me, and I had delivered about 100 babies and taken care of even more. But when it came to my own, that didn't help me *at all!*

Comment: @anongoodnurse It absolutely is...I suppose I'll just have to deal with the fussiness, and try to distract him while strapping it in (without doing so too tightly, of course).

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you replace the disposables with cloth -- just suggesting an experiment so you can make more observations.  Maybe it's a sensory thing, maybe it's the pressure, etc.  It can be hard to figure out, when the baby can't tell you! / You can discuss this with the pediatrician or nurse at the doctor's office.

Answer (score 4):

So I did figure something out - it seems like he gets bored when I'm changing him, and begins to fuss as I'm strapping him in.

Handing him a soft, safe toy to play with seems to help - so I've taken to doing that with each changing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about the "strapping it onto his body". The diaper tabs don't attach to the child, they attach to the front of the diaper.

You may need to check that you're putting it on correctly. The velcro/sticky tabs should not be touching his skin at all, and if they are, I can understand how this would likely be very uncomfortable.

Also check that you're not making it too tight. It just needs to be tight enough that it doesn't fall off.

You could also perhaps try a different brand. We tried various brands until we found one that worked well.

Comment: Yes, I do mean strapping onto his diaper more specifically - which then keeps the diaper wrapped around his body.

Comment: @Zibbobz I'd suggest you check carefully all around the edges of the diaper to ensure there's no rough, plastic type material rubbing uncomfortably against his skin. If a 4 month old is getting distressed by something like this, it seems most likely that something on the diaper is causing physical discomfort. If there's nothing obvious, then I'd suggest you try different diaper brands, to see if this may help. They vary quite a lot, and we found that even some of the most common brands didn't work well at all.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but I suspect it's because the answer here is phrased as more of a question to clarify the original question - you may want to edit it to be more clear that you're offering an answer (which you are) so that it's clear what your intention is.

Comment: Thanks @Zibbobz That makes sense. I've re-phrased it as a suggestion, rather than a question.